# How can I solve this system of equations??

Tags: systems-of-equations, symmetric-polynomials

I have this system of equations and I need values for $c_1, c_2, c_3, x_1, x_2, x_3$.
\begin{align*}
c_1 + c_2 + c_3 &= 2\\
c_1x_1 + c_2x_2+ c_3x_3 &= 0\\
c_1x_1^2 + c_2x_2^2+c_3x_3^2 &= \frac{2}{3}\\
c_1x_1^3 + c_2x_2^3+c_3x_3^3 &= 0\\
c_1x_1^4 + c_2x_2^4 + c_3x_3^4 &= \frac{2}{5}\\
c_1x_1^5 + c_2x_2^5+c_3x_3^5 &= 0
\end{align*}

I have attempted using matrix but was unsuccessful. How can I obtain values for $x_i$ and $ c_i$?

Comment: A solution to this system, indeed there is. Nonlinear, the system is. Use linear matrix methods, you cannot. To solve this system, methods exist. Newton is one. Secant another. Solving this problem well, Mathematica does. If pen and paper, you must use, then Gram-Schmidt integration may prove helpful. Though certain of this, I am not.

Comment: @Corp.andLtd.: There are six solutions. An example is $$c_1 = \dfrac{5}{9}, c_2 = \dfrac{5}{9}, c_3 = \dfrac{8}{9}, x_1 =- \sqrt{\dfrac{3}{5}}, x_2 = \sqrt{\dfrac{3}{5}}, x_3 = 0$$ The other solutions are permutations of this solution.

Comment: I was eager  to know solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewriting the system as
\begin{align} 
\sum_{j=1}^3 c_j\,x_j^i&=v_i,\quad i=0,\dots,5
\tag{1}\label{1}
,
\end{align}

we can apply [Prony's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prony%27s_method) 
as follows.
Solve the linear system
\begin{align} 
\left[\begin{matrix}
v_0 & v_1 & v_2 \\
v_1 & v_2 & v_3 \\
v_2 & v_3 & v_4 
\end{matrix}\right]
\cdot
\left[\begin{matrix}
a_0 \\ a_1 \\ a_2
\end{matrix}\right]
&=
\left[\begin{matrix}
 v_3 \\ v_4 \\ v_5
\end{matrix}\right]
\end{align}

for $a_0,a_1,a_2$.

The roots of polynomial

\begin{align} 
x^3-a_2\,x^2-a_1\,x-a_0
\end{align}

would be the triple $x_1,x_2,x_3$.
Given that, the solution of another linear system

\begin{align} 
\left[\begin{matrix}
1&1&1 \\
x_1&x_2&x_3 \\
x_1^2&x_2^2&x_3^2 
\end{matrix}\right]
\cdot
\left[\begin{matrix}
 c_1 \\ c_2 \\ c_3
\end{matrix}\right]
&=
\left[\begin{matrix}
 v_0 \\ v_1 \\ v_2
\end{matrix}\right]
\end{align}

for $c_1,c_2,c_3$ completes the answer.

In numbers we have

\begin{align}
\left[\begin{matrix}
 2 & 0 & \tfrac23 \\
 0 & \tfrac23 & 0 \\
 \tfrac23  & 0 & \tfrac25  
\end{matrix}\right]
\cdot
\left[\begin{matrix}
 a_0 \\ a_1 \\ a_2
\end{matrix}\right]
&=
\left[\begin{matrix}
 0 \\ \tfrac25 \\ 0
\end{matrix}\right]
,\\
\end{align}

\begin{align}
a_0&=0,\quad a_1=\tfrac35.\quad a_2=0
,\\
x^3-\tfrac35\,x&=0
,\\
x_1&=0,\quad x_2=\tfrac{\sqrt{15}}5
,\quad x_3=-\tfrac{\sqrt{15}}5
.
\end{align}

The system for $c_j$:

\begin{align} 
\left[\begin{matrix}
 1&1&\phantom{-}1 \\
 0& \tfrac{\sqrt{15}}5 & -\tfrac{\sqrt{15}}5 \\
 0& \tfrac35 & \phantom{-}\tfrac35 
\end{matrix}\right]
\cdot
\left[\begin{matrix}
 c_1 \\ c_2 \\ c_3
\end{matrix}\right]
&=
\left[\begin{matrix}
 2 \\ 0 \\ \tfrac23
\end{matrix}\right]
,\\
\end{align}

which results in
\begin{align} 
c_1&=\tfrac89,\quad 
c_2= c_3=\tfrac59
.
\end{align}